# I am working on Bootstrap spinners , i am stuck with load spinner whenever we click a button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bootstrap-4, kpi

```
<div class="container">
<h1 id="Tickets"><span class="spinner-grow text-muted"></span></h1>
</div>
```

1. Here i am showing a normal bootstrap spinner. it can be visiable whenever we load html page.
   2)i need to run whenever we click a button.after getting output spinner should be stop, if we again press the button again spinner should be visible

```
$(document).ready(function (data) {
  $("#btnGo").click(function () {
}
}
[![need to load spinner inside kpi widget][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the spinner:

```
<span class="spinner-grow text-muted" id='spinner'></span>
```

When you want to show the spinner:

```
$("#spinner").removeClass("d-none");
```

When you want to hide the spinner:

```
$("#spinner").addClass("d-none");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the spinner by just adding a class to it.
Like

```
.hidden {
 display:none;
}
```

Then apply this class whenever your ajax request is complete and remove when clicking the button.

Disabling Spinner

```
$.ajax({
..
complete:function(){
   $("#spinner").addClass("hidden")
}
})
```

Showing Spinner

```
$("#btnGo").click(function () {
  $("#spinner").removeClass("hidden");
}
```